# Iterate through a foreachloop in razorview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a collection being returned to me.  I am currently looping through my collection and displaying everything found in the Model.  However, I only want the 5 most recent things displayed.  For example the Model contains 25 
"things" I would only like to display 5 of them, without putting everything into an array first. I'm thinking an if statement with a counter possibly.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model IEnumerable<Does.Not.Matter>
<h2>THINGS!!</h2>
@if(Model != null)
{

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        @foreach (var things in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@things.thing1</td>
                <td>@things.thing2</td>
                <td>@things.thing3</td>
                <td>@things.thing4</td>
                <td>@things.thing5</td>
                <td>@things.thing6</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>    
}
```

Comment: `I only want the 5 most recent things` - Do you have any property on records which would allow to identify recent? Apply sorting and as @David suggested in his answer `Take(5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the first 5 records:

```
@foreach (var things in Model.Take(5))
```

Comment: Thank you David!  I knew it was easy I just couldn't remember the syntax. Been awhile since I used MVC.  I appreciate it!

Comment: @Tim `Take(5) `is `LINQ` not `MVC`. :)